# How to set the date from DatePicker dialog for multiple calls

Tags: android

Good day, can't seem to find a solution for this. i have 2 buttons that when pressed, opens a datepickerdialog, but my problem now is , how can i set them to the appropriate button on OnDateSet method. I am using a DialogFragment for the date and then implementing the DateListener in my activity. I have tried using getTag() but no success in getting the tag. here is what i tried:

```
public void showfromDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment dateFragment = new DateDialogFragment();
        dateFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fromdatePicker");
    }

    public void showtoDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment dateFragment = new DateDialogFragment();
        dateFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "todatePicker");
    }


        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(day).append("-")
               .append(month).append("-")
               .append(year);

        String text= builder.toString();

        if(view.getTag().toString().equals("fromdatePicker")) { // error here

            Log.d(TAG, "got here" + text);
            fromdate.setText(text);
        }


        if(view.getTag() == "todatePicker") {
            todate.setText(text);
        }
```

any ideas how to implement this? i keep seeing solutions about using 2 different DialogFragment class but am guessing there should be another way. or am i wrong? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to get selected date from DatePicker or else?

Comment: @Deepika yes. thats what i want to do. i just did not bother adding the code in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i have a work around for these. which can be helpful for anyone with this problem. if its slightly incorrect please let me know and i can change it. but this is what i did to solve this issue.

in on DateSet:

```
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(day).append("-")
               .append(month).append("-")
               .append(year);

        String text= builder.toString();

FragmentManager fragmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();

      if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("fromdatePicker") != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "got here" + text);
            fromdate.setText(text);
        }



       // if(view.getTag() == "todatePicker") {
  if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("todatePicker") != null) {
            todate.setText(text);
        }
```

that way you can use the same dateListener for multiple calls and set the date appropriately based on the tag that was passed when calling show on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code of DatePicker Dialog.

```
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay; 
Calendar cal4DatePicker = Calendar.getInstance();
Button btnDOB=findviewbyId(R.id.btndob);

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;

        cal4DatePicker.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
        cal4DatePicker.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
        cal4DatePicker.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);

        btnDOB.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(mDay).append("-").append(mMonth).append("-").append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
};
```

on btnDOB you need to set click listner to show this DatePicker Dialog.

Comment: yes.. this solution works, but that means i have to have multiple different dateListeners if there are multiple buttons triggering DatePickers dialog

Answer (score 1):

I have try same thing with Time Picker only. You can try out and set same for date picker also.

```
    package com.example.toolboxtest;


import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button testBtn; 
    EditText testET;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    int mHour = 0;
    int mMinute = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testBTn);
        testET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testET);

        testBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.testBTn:
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            break;
        }

    }
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour=hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
//          myPrefs = ImportantDateReminderActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
//          prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); 
//          prefsEditor.putInt("hour", mHour);
//          prefsEditor.putInt("minute", mMinute);
//          prefsEditor.putString("a", a);
//          prefsEditor.commit();
            if(mHour==12){                 
                //reminderSetTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append("12").append(":").append((minute)+" PM"));
                testET.setText(mHour+":"+mMinute+" "+"PM");

            }
            else             
                updateTimeDisplay();         
        } 
    };

    private void updateTimeDisplay() {          
        try {             
            Format formatter;             
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");             
            Date d = df.parse(mHour + ":" + mMinute);             
            Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();             
            gc.setTime(d);             
            //gc.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);             
            Date d2 = gc.getTime();  

            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");             
            String time = formatter.format(d2);   
            System.out.println("The TIME is: "+time);
            testET.setText(time);

            String hour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh").format(d2);
            String minute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(d2);
            String a = new SimpleDateFormat("a").format(d2);
            System.out.println("The Hour is: "+hour+ " "+minute+ " " +a);
            /*myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); 
            prefsEditor.putInt("hour", Integer.parseInt(hour));
            prefsEditor.putInt("minute", Integer.parseInt(minute));
            prefsEditor.putString("a", a);
            prefsEditor.putString("complateTime", time);
            prefsEditor.commit();*/

            //addTwoMonthNotification();
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();         
        }      
    } 

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Please let me know if there is any issue.